# Page not found 404 on Django server?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, url-mapping

I am doing a Django course and in my first tutorial only I am getting "Page on found 404 error" while mapping the URL will the view. 
I referred to this link and did same steps I am still getting same error.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

```
polls/urls.py
-------------
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

```
polls/view.py
-------------
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

```
mysite/urls.py
--------------
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [
  path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ]
```

[Directory of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CgiK.png)

Help me with the error... I checked all sources and followed exactly the link... Still cannot run it properly

Comment: What url are you visiting?

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/polls/` should work.

Comment: if you are attempting to visit `http://localhost:8000` then change `path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),` to `path('', include('polls.urls')),`

Comment: in `urls.py` you do `from . import views` but your file seems to be named `view.py`. Or maybe it's just a typo in your post ?